# Why is my css opacity not transitioning back to its original state of .5 with setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am relatively new to JS, Jquery, and CSS.

I am looking to write a Simon Says style game. When I try to animate the computer to automatically light up the desired square, I do not get the desired results.

My solution is to have the colored squares start at an opacity of 0.5.
Each square has an ID. When that ID matches the correct number, I use

$(this).css("opacity","1"); to brighten it

I do not know how to get the square to automatically change back to .5

I have tried using a setTimeout() function to delay the change back. Even though the code delays It doesn't change back. I have used both an empty space and .5 as values

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matchy Matchy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simonSays.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Match the Colors!</h1>
    <div id="banner">
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        <span id="level">Level:1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square" id="1"></div>
        <div class="square" id="2"></div>
        <div class="square" id="3"></div>
        <div class="square" id="4"></div>
        <div class="square" id="5"></div>
        <div class="square" id="6"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="simonSays.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body{
    background-color:black;
    margin:0;
}

h1{
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:steelblue;
    margin:0;
}

#banner{
    background-color:white;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
}


#container{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.square{
    background-color:pink;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    width:30%;
    margin:1.66%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    --webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    --moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```
//variables
var level = 1;

//add event listeners for player use
//probably can make a class and use toggle to shorten code
$(".square").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("opacity","1");
});
$(".square").on("mouseleave",function(){
   $(this).css("opacity",".5"); 
});

init();
doLevel(level); //test

function init(){
    //go through all squares and add a random color as background
    $(".square").each(function(i, obj){
        $(obj).css("backgroundColor", generateRandomColor());
    });
}

function doLevel(level){
    //get the colors to copy
    var pattern = selectColors(level);
    //showPattern(pattern);
    //test
    console.log(pattern[0]);
}


function generateRandomColor(){
    var color = "";
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    var color = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    return color;
}

function selectColors(amount){
    //declare array to hold values
    var order = [];
    //loop through amount
    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        order.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
    }

    return order;

}

function showPattern(pattern){
    //for each number in pattern,
    for(var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++){
        //for each square on the screen
        $(".square").each(function(j,obj){
            var $this = $(this); //settimeout changes to global, so I am declaring locally here
            //if the ID is equal to the pattern number
            if(parseInt($(this).attr("id")) === parseInt(pattern[i])){
                //brighten
                console.log("light up");
                $(this).css("opacity","1");
                //dim
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("changing back");
                    $this.css("opacity",".5");
                }, 3000);

            }
        })
    }
}
```

I expect the opacity to go back to .5, but the style is staying as 1. Nothing I try changes it back.
So one I am looking to understand why it won't change,
And two, if there is a better way to implement this I would love to know.

thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a working example where we can see the code and debug it?

Comment: Posted all the code I have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout resets the this pointer to the global scope and you will end up with issues.  If you use the object in the each call all is well in the world ;)

Also keep in mind that opacity is a number value so no need for quotes when setting it.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.square').each((i, e) => {
    $(e).css('opacity', 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(e).css('opacity', 0.5)
    }, 3000)
  });
});
```

```css
.square{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Another option for fun is to use jQuery animate.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.square').each((i, e) => {
    $(e).css('opacity', 1).animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.square{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```